# Firebase prevent to delete data using rule

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have public Firebase  data (lets say list of teachers), any one can add/update teacher but don't want to allow to delete.
I tried by using data.exists() and newData.exists() with different combination but no achievement yet.

```js
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": false,
    "teachers": {
      ".write": "data.exists() || !newData.exists()"
      }
}
```

I want to avoid/restrict following Ionic operation

```
refrence.orderByChild("postedDate").on('value', function(snapshot) {
    if(snapshot.val()){
        snapshot.forEach(function(request) {
                request.ref().remove();                     
        });
    }
});
```

How can I get footprints of activities for specific date/time period
Can I get backup for specific date?

Comment: Did you try `".write": "(data.exists() && newData.exists()) || (!data.exists() && newData.exists())"`?

Comment: Please edit your question to show the code for an operation that succeeds and that you want to fail.

Comment: You're asking several questions here.  Please only ask one question at a time.

Comment: @AlissonEnz tried but it not restrict to delete data

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks for recommendation, question edited